# Давайте отображать метки в комментариях как в постах (вопросах/ответах)

Tags: предложение, метки, дизайн, комментарии

Если я напишу в вопросе `[meta-tag:метка]` в вопросе, это будет отображаться таким образом

[метка](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0)

но в комментариях это будет отображаться как ссылка: [метка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Я [предложил на главной мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298027/346987) отображать ссылки на метки точно также как и в постах (вопросах/ответах).

#### Предложение на главной мете

Но предложение скорее было отвергнуто, так как некоторые посчитали, что это будет выглядеть "навязчиво".

Поэтому проголосуйте за (или против) [пост на главной мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298027/346987), если вам нравится (не нравится) это предолжение.

Comment: Проголосовал на главной мете против, т.к. также считаю, что "комменты должны быть легковесными". А текущему посту даже затрудняюсь дать оценку: в пиаре главной меты не вижу ничего дурного, тут уже были подобные пиары, а отрицательное отношение уже выразил на главной мете, получается, что этот вопрос я должен ни плюс не ставить, ни минус? Не могу понять минусующих: это дополнительный минус предложению или минус стремлению попиарить вопрос на другой мете?

Comment: @AK Ну раз не согласны, то можете минус ставить за несогласие с самим предложением. Я без обид если что.

Comment: Тут надысь были выборы модератора чата и я это уже видел: как голосовали против самой идеи выборов модераторов и поэтому каждому кандидату дополнительно ставили минус. Но если вы хотите продублировать вопрос там и тут -- тогда напишите явно, я проголосую и тут.

Answer (score 4):

## Нужен другой способ выделения

Я согласен, что было бы хорошо отображать метки в комментариях как-то не так, как обычные ссылки, но вариант с отображением из ответов не подходит, поскольку он уж слишком выделяющийся, а метки в комментариях не значат ничего настолько существенного, чтобы им надо было в первую очередь бростаться в глаза. Даже если в тексте ответа встречается [метка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0), она изменяет высоту текущей строки по сравнению с другим текстом - а что уж говорить о комментариях.

Comment: они ж не как [обычные](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/) ссылки: [meta-tag:tag]. Хотя нет, как

Comment: Хм. Почему не предложили выделять другим цветом? Кажется, это очевидное решение, которое автоматом приходит в голову. Или заменить dotted на что-то иное.